# Ruby on Rails: how to incorporate spreadsheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

I would like to have an editable spreadsheet on my RoR app where users can input information (most importantly I would like them to be able to paste in data copied from excel for example) and then save the data to my database.

Could you guys point me to something that could help me achieve this goal? I've tried DHTMLX but it doesn't allow pasting in many rows of data at once.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using http://handsontable.com/ very nice javascript package that I was able to incorporate into rails!

Answer (score 0):

a version without spending money?

is use google drive for ruby Gem.

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby